# Store draggable DIV's position to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to know if/how id be able to store the position of where I move a draggable div to on the screen, so that when the page is reloaded, it will return to were it was left.

The code is here

```js
function drag_start(event) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain",
    (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"),10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"),10) - event.clientY));
} 
function drag_over(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    return false; 
} 
function drop(event) { 
    var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
    var dm = document.getElementById('dragme');
    dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0],10)) + 'px';
    dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10)) + 'px';
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
} 
var dm = document.getElementById('dragme'); 
dm.addEventListener('dragstart',drag_start,false); 
document.body.addEventListener('dragover',drag_over,false); 
document.body.addEventListener('drop',drop,false);
```

```css
aside { 
    position:  absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0; /* set these so Chrome doesn't return 'auto' from getComputedStyle */
    width: 200px; 
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.66); 
    border: 2px  solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    border-radius: 4px; padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<aside draggable="true" id="dragme">
    This is an aside, drag me.
</aside>
<p>I never am really satisfied that I understand anything; because, understand it well as I may, my comprehension can only be an infinitesimal fraction of all I want to understand about the many connections and relations which occur to me, how the matter in question was first thought of or arrived at, etc., etc.</p>
<p>In almost every computation a great variety of arrangements for the succession of the processes is possible, and various considerations must influence the selections amongst them for the purposes of a calculating engine. One essential object is to choose that arrangement which shall tend to reduce to a minimum the time necessary for completing the calculation.</p>
<p>Many persons who are not conversant with mathematical studies imagine that because the business of [Babbage’s Analytical Engine] is to give its results in numerical notation, the nature of its processes must consequently be arithmetical and numerical, rather than algebraical and analytical. This is an error. The engine can arrange and combine its numerical quantities exactly as if they were letters or any other general symbols; and in fact it might bring out its results in algebraical notation, were provisions made accordingly.</p>
<p>The Analytical Engine has no pretensions whatever to originate anything. It can do whatever we know how to order it to perform. It can follow analysis, but it has no power of anticipating any analytical revelations or truths. Its province is to assist us in making available what we are already acquainted with.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to store it in a DB? A user can have many devices on which layout of your site (and position of div therefore) is different.

Consider storing it in Local Storage or Cookie ([your example](https://jsfiddle.net/25fw1sdk/)).

```
var pos = {left: dm.style.left, top: dm.style.top};
document.cookie = JSON.stringify(pos);
try {
    var pos = JSON.parse(document.cookie);
    dm.style.left = pos.left ? pos.left : '0px';
    dm.style.top = pos.top ? pos.top : '0px';
} catch (e) {
    // Some error handling
}
```

Comment: This works great in your example, however when on my page, after a refresh it reverts back to the original position.

Comment: How would i go about storing multiple cookies? I'd like to have the date as the name of the cookie which would be obtained by <?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?>

Comment: @ZHolt `document.cookie` is a `key=value` string. So, just use `document.cookie = "date='"+JSON.stringify(pos)+"'"`. It will be appended to other cookies you have. But to get it you'll need to split this string (by `;`) and find a value that starts with `date=`. Better to use some library like js-cookie.

Comment: I've tried  `var str = JSON.stringify(pos);`
   `var dat = <?php echo $_GET[date];?>;`
   `document.cookie = +dat+"="+str;'  and changed '  var pos = JSON.parse(+dat);` but this doesn't work

Comment: What is `$_GET[date]`? Are you trying to store a cookie in a key you've got in HTTP Query? Probably you don't need leading `+` symbol. Also, check if dat variable contains value, maybe it should be `var dat = "<?php echo $_GET['date']; ?>";` (notice `"`)

Comment: The `$_GET[date]` will get the php  date variable from the URL e.g. if the URL is `www.example.com/test.php?date=100616`, it will get 100616. I have one page that's values change depending on what this date variable is, and depending on what that date is, the dragable div may be over a part of the page that has content

Comment: so if the user went to `www.example.com/test.php?date=100616` the dragable div may need to load in the center but if they went to `www.example.com/test.php?date=110616` they may have content in the center of the screen and would need to move it, but having only one cookie, if they went back on to `www.example.com/test.php?date=100616` that may then go over content on that page.

Comment: Code above should work. If it isn't, look at browser's developers tools.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you have to store in the database, you will have to use Ajax to communicate with the server (e.g. a PhP script on a web server) that will interact with the database. JavaScript cannot itself interact with a database.

Here you can find the W3C page talking about Ajax : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Pay attention to the different method on some browser like IE, some versions badly support the XmlHttpRequest object which is the Ajax base object.

In your case, depending on what you want to do, you can store only the position of the div and then at the loading of the page retrieve it for the database. Another solution, much more dirty I think, is to save the entire HTML page in the database. Ajax is able to send and bring back several types of data, such as JSON, raw text, XML, but also ready-to-use HTML that you can just inject in a div or anything else.

Hope it helps

EDIT : note that if you want to send large amount of data to the server you will have to use the POST method, which is not size-limited, instead of the GET method. GET will be ok for only sending the position of the div, but POST will be necessary if sending the full page. [See here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) for more details.